# Why result is different?

Tags: python, qwidget, pyside6

I'm going to separate files on pyside6. I divided Widget and separated files in my own way, but the results are different. Why is it different?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        central_widget = QWidget()

        widgetsss = QWidget()
        title_1 = QLabel("Title 1")
        title_2 = QLabel("Title 2")
        title_3 = QLabel("Title 3")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(title_1)
        layout.addWidget(title_2)
        layout.addWidget(title_3)
        widgetsss.setLayout(layout)

        widgetsss.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;")
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(widgetsss)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

Result is

[image]

other is

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        central_widget = QWidget()

        widgetsss = anoterwidget()

        widgetsss.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgreen;")
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(widgetsss)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


class anoterwidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        title_1 = QLabel("Title 1")
        title_2 = QLabel("Title 2")
        title_3 = QLabel("Title 3")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(title_1)
        layout.addWidget(title_2)
        layout.addWidget(title_3)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

result is

[image]

Why is there such a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing colors via set style-sheets can have undesired side effects. In order to control this a bit better, always mention [which component](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/overviews/stylesheet-syntax.html) you want to modify, e.g. `QLabel { #css_goes_here }`:

[image]

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Single Class")

        widg = QWidget()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        title_1 = QLabel("Title 1")
        title_2 = QLabel("Title 2")
        title_3 = QLabel("Title 3")

        layout.addWidget(title_1)
        layout.addWidget(title_2)
        layout.addWidget(title_3)
        widg.setLayout(layout)

        p = widg.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.red)
        widg.setPalette(p)

        widg.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color:pink;}")

        self.setCentralWidget(widg)


class MainWindow2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Double Class")
        widg = anoterwidget()
        widg.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color:lightgreen;}")
        self.setCentralWidget(widg)


class anoterwidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        title_1 = QLabel("Title 1")
        title_2 = QLabel("Title 2")
        title_3 = QLabel("Title 3")

        layout.addWidget(title_1)
        layout.addWidget(title_2)
        layout.addWidget(title_3)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window2 = MainWindow2()
    window.show()
    window2.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but there are some inaccuracies. First of all, the style sheet aspect is the most important issue, and should be better clarified: in the first case of the OP, since there are no selectors, the container gets the background along with the labels, so the *whole* area (including the layout margins) gets blue. The difference in layout margins only affects the outer border, and it's caused by the underlying style: when no layout margins are set, QLayout calls the `pixelMetric()` function of the *parent widget* style, which may have different results depending on the »

Comment: » widget type (or even consider the padding if set on the style sheet). By default, it returns 11 for top level windows, and 9 for container widgets; in your tests you probably called `contentsMargins()` *before* reparenting the inner widget. Also note that the selector should also be used in the second case: it doesn't change the result in your case because using QWidget subclasses prevent background drawing unless `Qt.WA_StyledBackground` is set (or another container type is used). Finally, using palette and stylesheet is discouraged as incompatible, since the stylesheet always takes »

Comment: » precedence (it actually internally overrides the palette of the widget whenever any standard color property is set, [see this related post](//stackoverflow.com/a/71231822)) and may cause inconsistencies due to propagation. In your case, using `setPalette()` didn't affect anything (mostly because you are not calling `setAutoFillBackground(True)`), but it's still very important to be aware of these aspects. Finally, while not strictly forbidden, we should avoid reentering the loop of a closed QApplication; for such an example, a QDialog.exec() would've probably been a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications @musicamante and sorry for the presented half-truths. It was a bit of an exploration on my part, as you can easily tell from my answer. I have "reduced" my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. What I felt was that it's not a common way to put widgets in widgets. I think it's a more efficient way to place them in center widgets with just a layout. But I have a lot of concerns when I want to split the code.